# Node.js: fs.unlink & fs.unlinkSycn

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to deleted a file and wait for the deletion to succeed before moving forward with the execution.

Can i use either of the below.

a) `await fs.unlink(path, callback);`

b) `fs.unlinkSync(path)`

which one of the above is the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I you do not want to do anything while deletion, `unlinkSync` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `await fs.promises.unlink(path)` or `fs.unlinkSync(path)`.

`await fs.unlink(path, callback)` is not a correct option as the `await` will not do anything useful because `fs.unlink()` does not return a promise.

The `await fs.promises.unlink(path)` option is asynchronous and will not block your process (allowing it to handle other events), but the `await` will suspend the local function execution until it is completed allowing you to sequence operations properly within that function.

The `fs.unlinkSync(path)` option is blocking and synchronous and should not be used in a server environment (because it wrecks server scalability), but can be used in a single user script or in server startup or shutdown code.

For any further advice on a choice between the two, we need to understand the context you are using them in (is this a server?) and see the relevant code around them.  There is a right and wrong place for each depending upon the circumstances of the code.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 for detailed explanation. I am generating a screenshot, uploading to s3, do some more processing and sending a response to a server. i want to delete the screenshot after uploading to s3. would `await fs.promises.unlink(path)` be ok in such case

Comment: @opensource-developer - Yes, that could work fine, if implemented properly.  You will, of course, have to be sure that the upload has completed (using the appropriate callback or promise notification).  If you show the code for the whole function, we can advise more accurately and make any other relevant suggestions.